# Handling plupload file uploads in Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, file-upload, plupload

I'm trying to write a controller to accept file uploads from the [Plupload](http://www.plupload.com/) plugin. As an added bit of fun, the uploads are coming from a different URL so I have to set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header myself. So far I've done that like so:

```
/**
 * @Route("/frontEnd/file/upload.{_format}")
 */
public function upload(Request $request) {
    $response = new Response();
    $response->setContent(json_encode(array('hello' => 'world')));
    $response->setStatusCode(200);
    $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    $response->send();
}
```

which seems to work. When I submit the uploads using plupload I see the XHR requests hit Symfony and the JSON is returned. However, I have no idea how to handle the actual file and move it into a directory.

I did a `var_dump()` on `$_POST` and it only returned the following:

```
array(1) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(21) "wallpaper-2873928.jpg"
}
```

The upload is definitely being sent as I can see the file's bytes being part of the request payload with developer tools. Do I need to use Symfony's own components to handle the upload? If so, how? The Symfony documentation only seems to cover uploading from a file upload form.

Comment: handle it like a normal upload, the plugin should push the file like a form upload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, try to use the Symfony2 way of accessing request parameters. You can get more information in the [book](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/http_fundamentals.html).

When uploading a file, Symfony2 automatically creates an instance of [UploadedFile](http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/UploadedFile.html) for you and puts it in a [FileBag](http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/FileBag.html) in the request object.

You can access the files in your controller like this:

```
$files = $request->files;
```

Like said previously, these are temporary files. To upload them in a user defined directory, use the `move` method on the object.

```
$directory = //...

foreach ($files as $uploadedFile) {
    $name = //...
    $file = $uploadedFile->move($directory, $name);
}
```

The variable `$files` now contains an instance of [File](http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/File.html).

---

On the other hand, you can also use a bundle that supports the Plupload uploader. I'd recommend the [OneupUploaderBundle](https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupUploaderBundle). (Note: I'm the main developer of this bundle, I guess this needs to be added).